# Spring MVC - controllers not loaded

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

After switching from full annotation to half-xml-half-annotation configuration, my application stopped working. Every request results in 404, when I tried debugging, the controller methods were not called.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-web-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

**spring-web-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <!-- Scan the JavaConfig -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="vn.fpt.fsoft.csms" />

</beans>
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "vn.fpt.fsoft.csms")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public final void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver =
                new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

**HomeController.java**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        System.out.println("elelee");
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

**Tomcat log**

```
15-Aug-2016 06:47:44.136 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
15-Aug-2016 06:47:44.871 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring-web'
```

Comment: Why are using half annotation and half xml based approach??

And what is the package structure?

Comment: @RavindraDevadiga Because I found out that there was no alternative for jsp-config in java config, and I don't like xml config. The structure is just a standard maven + web structure. BTW, I tried removing the <jsp-config> and everything worked fine, but I kinda need it, and I don't know what's wrong

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I just had to change the  to

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```